# Как обратиться к методу класса через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет опять) Пишу свой движок (Фреймворк) в целях саморазвития и глубокого изучения php.  Есть форма (может и не форма а просто input с кнопкой, или только одна кнопка, или тупо ссылка). Задача по нажатии вызвать метод класса. Это может быть регистрация/авторизация, создание/изменение данных... Не важно. Как обратиться к методу класса через ajax?

Comment: "Как обратиться к методу класса через ajax" --- точно так же, как и не через ajax. url обращения будет ровно таким же

Comment: @АлексейШиманский увы, для того кто только учит, всё не так просто

Comment: @InDevX что именно не просто? тот же самый url написать не просто?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да сама концепция, как оно работает - этого в 90% не понимают, а не понимая как оно работает то часто даже ссылка есть проблемой (я лектор, если что, знаю о чем говорю, на хабр по этой теме огромную статью готовлю)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вызвать какой-то промежуточный скрипт вида

```
require_once('User.php'); // подключение класса
$model = new User; // инициализация модели
print_r($model->$_POST['method']($_POST['params'])); // вызов метода класса и передача ему параметров
```

Внутри ajax вы передаете данные в таком виде

```
data: {
    method: 'methodName',
    params: {
       uid: user_id,
    }
}
```

Comment: `$model->{$_POST['method']}($_POST['params'])`

Comment: Да, это я знаю. Просто если у меня есть, например, класс User и у него 20 методов, то для каждого придется создать 20 файлов со скриптами. А если классов хотя бы 5, то это уже 100 файлов. Я просто подумал, может есть какой то способ обратиться к методу класса напрямую из js файла?

Comment: Зачем для каждого создавать файл со скриптами? Вы создаете 1 файл как у меня в примере, и он будет вызывать соответствующие методы вашего класса. Вам нужно лишь будет указывать метод класса в параметрах